# Are entities fetched outside transaction managed or detached?

Tags: java, jpa

I always thought that entities fetched before a transaction (before `entityManager.getTransaction().begin()`) were detached from the persistence context (while using the same entity manager to fetch entities as to handle the transaction). In fact, every time I was managing transactions, I had to explicitly merge entities that were fetched outside of it. If I didn't, updates were not reflected in the database.

But recently, I had a discussion with a colleague who experienced this situation the opposite way. He had to explicitly detach every entities fetched before transaction to avoid updating database.

The only difference between our codes is that my `persistence.xml` file is version 2.0 and his is version 1.0. But he is using JPA 2.1 in his code. Is that the reason for this strange behavior or is there something I'm missing here?

We both use Hibernate as implementation.

Comment: They will be managed.

Comment: what implementation do you use?

Answer (score 2):

PersistenceContext may have two scopes:

- TRANSACTIONAL-SCOPE
- EXTENDED-SCOPE

---

**TRANSACTIONAL-SCOPE**

Occurs only when EntityManager is container-managed. In this case, current PersistenceContext is active as long as current transaction exists.

**EXTENDED-SCOPE**

Occurs when EntityManager is application-managed (be default) or container-managed (EntityManager  needs annotation: `@PersistenceContext( type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)` ).

Long story short: EXTENDED-SCOPE means that current PersistenceContext lives as long as your bean lives.

Comment: As I didn't use the annotation @PersistenceContext, I should be in transactional-scope, which would explain why my pre-transactional loaded entities are not managed. Though, I don't think my colleague use that annotation as well, but I can't be certain for now. I will figure it out when he arrives.

Comment: Exdending scope from transactional to extended is caussed not by the 'PersistenceContext' annotation itself, but by the 'type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED' formula. If you don't use PersistenceContext annotation, that means that your EntityManager is  application-managed, which results in extended scope. Remember, every time you invoke 'emf.createEntityManager' you create new PersistenceContext- maybe here is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If and how things merge automatically into a transactional context depends on several factors. The JPA implementation in use, the persistence context scope, and also the transaction isolation in use. Without seeing the whole environment this cannot easily be answered. I would **assume** your application allows non transactional reads (dirty read, phantom read, non-repeatable read) and hence you are "allowed" to decide wether you want to merge. 
Another explanation could be some probem with your application code mixing several persistence contexts and hence requiring you to merge your entities read in one persistence context into another persitence context (the one which you started your TX on).

Comment: I edited my post to precise what implementation of JPA I'm using: Hibernate. As stated in another comment, I don't use @PersistenceContext annotation and so I should be, by default, in transactional-scope but I could be wrong. I use only one entity manager, so I should have only one persistence context (if I understood well how it works).

Answer (score 0):

They will be managed. Any changes will be reflected to the DB within next `flush`. Transaction commits are flushed right away, along with the changes enqueued by pre-transactional actions.

Comment: The fact is that things didn't go this way for me. Pre-transactional actions were not flushed into database. I had to explicitly merge entities fetched before transaction begins if I wanted them to be managed!

Comment: Than they had to be detached at some point. Having transaction or not. Maybe you are fetching them in different persistance context (different EntityManager) or maybe EntityManager is closed semewhere between your read and write. There is no other way. If you fetch entities, they are managed till you detach them or EM will be closed and all chenges will be reflected in the DB